# Limit bandwidth when testing MVC web application in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way of limiting the bandwidth of the connection to the test server that runs locally when testing a web application in Visual Studio?

You would want this, for exmaple, to be able to test loading animations or file upload processesing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), go to the Rules menu and then Performance / Simulate modem speeds.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are tools like NetLimiter (http://www.netlimiter.com/) and NetBalancer(http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/).

Both allow you to limit traffic either globally or for specific applications (which might be handy). I used NetLimiter in the past, NetBalancer seems to have better support for Windows 8 though.

Comment: Aren't these programs only used to limit actual network connections? I just had a look at NetBalancer and didn't find a way to do, what I actually want to do.

Comment: With NetBalancer you can:

Set for any process a download and/or upload network priority or limit
Manage priorities and limits for each network adapter separately (from the website)

Comment: Have you tried this with IIS Express before? In my case, its process doesn't show up in the list.

Comment: I'vs used NetLimiter before, but on my machine the process is called IIS Express worker process (iisexpress.ece located in C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express)